# Python numeric format

Tags: python, format, numeric

What is a good way to format a python decimal like this way?

115 --> 115.00

And

4,224 --> 4,224.00

Comment: If you have another question, the correct way is to ask a new question, not to edit your old question into something entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using python 3.6+, a good option is f-strings:

```
f'{115:,.2f}'
f'{4224:,.2f}'
```

If the 4224 is actually a string (maybe because of the comma), you will need to transform it to a number before `f"{int('4,224'.replace(',','')):,.2f}"`